# Can semifreddo be used in fried ice cream recipe?

Tags: substitutions, ice-cream

As the title says, can I use semifreddo instead of ice cream in a fried ice cream recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes and no. A lot of recipes for semifreddo aren't truly semifreddo because they are hard frozen. Recipes like that can be fried just like ice cream. The key to fried ice cream is to hard freeze the scoops of ice cream. By definition, that isn't semifreddo, but definitions don't seem to matter much to writers of recipes. So, if the "stuff" is hard frozen, it can be coated and fried like fried ice cream. Perhaps after being deep fried, the name "semifreddo" is more apropos.